# "Helpful flags" count is not updating

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, flags, vote-to-close

Recently I got privileges to cast **close/open** votes.

[image]

I did that moderation, but I observed that flags are now not updating.

[image]

I mean, the question which I have cast was not even listed out in the **Flagged Posts** question list.

So that's it. Will it stop from this stage? Do I know even which question was flagged by me (history of flags)?

Comment: Voting to close is not the same as flagging. When you vote to close, you'll no longer add to your flag count.

Comment: And before this privileges it is counted right?

Comment: Yes, before this privilege you were only flagging to close.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Prior to earning the privilege to vote to close, you were flagging items to close.  These would head into the Close Vote review queue where users with closing privileges would vote to close. The flags would add to your helpful count when the reviewers agreed with your original flag.

Now you've earned the privilege to vote to close.  The process is similar, in that when you vote to close it will go to the review queue, but you'll no longer add to your helpful flag count.

There are other ways to earn helpful flags once you get the privilege to vote to close.  You can help clean-up the site by flagging low quality answers, as well as answers that are "Not An Answer".  Then, if you come across something that seems like it needs a moderator to attend to, you'd use a custom "Other" flag to explain what needs to be done.

You'll still be able to increase your flag count, you'll just do it in different ways now.  Some of which I've outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172075/164200).

Comment: Shouldn't this question now be tagged [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?